# Questions for improving MySQL replication performance

Tags: mysql, performance, replication

I'm using MySQL 5.5.

My master DB has a very large amount of data and having data continually loaded. And I have only one slave DB. Because MySQL replication is single-threaded, so it's really slow to catch up...

I currently know two ways to improve the speed. One is to update MySQL to 5.6 which supports Multi-Threaded Slave. Another way is to separate one DB to multi DB on one slave(http://d2-systems.blogspot.com/2011/04/mysql-56x-feature-preview-multi.html).

Is there any other ways I can improve the replication loading speed? I have a tool need to get data from my slave DB. So if I choose to implement the second way, it will change a lot code from my tool.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try out [Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) is a high performance, open source, data replication engine for MySQL. It offers a set of features that surpass any open source replicator available today: global transaction IDs to support failover, flexible transaction filtering, extensible transaction metadata, sharding, multiple replication services per process, high performance, and simple, well-documented operation.

For more information about this utility you can visit:

http://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-replicator